# cannot add role on service account GCP IAM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I am trying to add role cloud sql client to my service account but got this warning [Utilization analysis for this binding has not been processed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xramV.jpg)

because of this i unable to use the service account for my application

how i fix this?

Comment: How did you proceed?

Comment: on the IAM, i just add/edit permission on service account
beforehand is working fine

Comment: Did you do that on the `IAM & ADMIN -> IAM` page or `IAM & ADMIN -> Service Account` page?

Comment: IAM & ADMIN -> IAM and i edit one of member/service registered on the list
is not working on member or service account

Comment: What are your permission on the project? Are you Project Owner or Security Admin?

Comment: i'm security admin and editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be seeing **?** icon which shows: "**Utilization analysis for this binding has not been processed**".
It is not a warning, and probably not the reason for your issue.
Check [this](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/recommender-overview#availability)

For newly created service accounts (managed by google) Utilization analysis is calculated after 90 days, after which it gives recommendations on Permissions that are not needed for that service account ie. Analyzed Permissions.

Comment: oh ok i seems understand now, on the IAM page there is service account with editor role and this is created by google i can use this service account for connect to my cloud sql. but i still confused why i cannot add role to the member on IAM page and got ? icon . i'm totaly sure i have permission